# Dense Optical Flow and Object Detection on a video using Python

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, opticalflow

I am trying to use dense Optical flow and Object detection in a video for each frame. Basically if I use only Object Detection using Yolo model, it will not give object bounding box for each frame of the video. Sometimes it is missed. In order to make it smooth, I want to use dense Optical flow so that if for some of the frame Yolo does not detect the object then optical flow output can be used to create bounding box of the object. Below is the code I am using to integrate dense optical flow and object detection using Yolo.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import sys
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
confidence = 0.5
threshold= 0.3
labelsPath = "C:/Users/Akash Jain/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo-coco/coco.names"
LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")
np.random.seed(42)
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),dtype="uint8")
weightsPath = "C:/Users/Akash Jain/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo-coco/yolov3.weights"
configPath = "C:/Users/Akash Jain/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/yolo-coco/yolov3.cfg"
# load our YOLO object detector trained on COCO dataset (80 classes)
print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)
ln = net.getLayerNames()
ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
writer = None
(W, H) = (None, None)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/Akash Jain/Downloads/yolo-object-detection/videos/overpass.mp4")
try:
    prop = cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
    total = int(cap.get(prop))    
    print("[INFO] {} total frames in video".format(total))
except:
    print("[INFO] could not determine # of frames in video")
    total = -1
# ret = a boolean return value from getting the frame, first_frame = the first frame in the entire video sequence
ret, first_frame = cap.read()
# Converts frame to grayscale because we only need the luminance channel for detecting edges - less computationally expensive
prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Creates an image filled with zero intensities with the same dimensions as the frame
mask = np.zeros_like(first_frame)
# Sets image saturation to maximum
mask[..., 1] = 255
dir_name='C:/Users/Akash Jain/Documents/ZED/Split'
base_filename='output'
filename_suffix = 'png'
fno=1
while(cap.isOpened()):    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    if W is None or H is None:
        (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Calculates dense optical flow by Farneback method
    # https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray, gray, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    # Computes the magnitude and angle of the 2D vectors
    magnitude, angle = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
    # Sets image hue according to the optical flow direction
    mask[..., 0] = angle * 180 / np.pi / 2
    # Sets image value according to the optical flow magnitude (normalized)
    mask[..., 2] = cv2.normalize(magnitude, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    # Converts HSV to RGB (BGR) color representation
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR) 
    # Opens a new window and displays the output frame
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    start = time.time()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
    end = time.time()
    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classIDs = []    
    for output in layerOutputs:       
        for detection in output:            
            scores = detection[5:]
            classID = np.argmax(scores)           
            confidence = scores[classID]
            if confidence > 0.5:
                box = detection[0:4] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
                (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
                x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
                boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                classIDs.append(classID)
            idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5,0.3)            
            if len(idxs) > 0:                
                for i in idxs.flatten():
                    (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
                    (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])
                    color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                    text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]], confidences[i])
                    cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, color, 2)

    print("frame",fno) 
    #print(text)
    print("boxes",boxes)
    print("confidence",confidences)
    print("classes",classIDs)
    print("object detection") 
    print(frame.shape)
    #print(frame)
    print("optical")
    #print(rgb)
    print(rgb.shape)
    output = ((1 * frame) + (0.5 * rgb)).astype("uint8")
    newpath= os.path.join(dir_name, str(fno) + "." + filename_suffix)
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    plt.imshow(output)    
    plt.show() 
    prev_gray = gray
    fno = int(fno)+1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I run this code, I get the following output.

```
[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...
[INFO] 812 total frames in video
frame 1
boxes [[622, 264, 14, 12], [675, 275, 20, 20], [574, 293, 22, 18], [495, 334, 49, 29], [525, 374, 49, 50]]
confidence [0.8653988242149353, 0.6596917510032654, 0.9037992358207703, 0.9345515966415405, 0.8292896747589111]
classes [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
object detection
(720, 1280, 3)
optical
(720, 1280, 3)
```

[image]

```
frame 2
boxes [[622, 264, 14, 12], [674, 275, 21, 20], [573, 293, 23, 18], [495, 334, 50, 29], [518, 378, 57, 52]]
confidence [0.8665716648101807, 0.6463424563407898, 0.9210211038589478, 0.8402170538902283, 0.5718783140182495]
classes [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
object detection
(720, 1280, 3)
optical
(720, 1280, 3)
```

[image]

Any input which can help me leverage the output of dense optical flow to create the bounding box for object if it is missed by object detection model so that it detects the object in each frame. The reason I am doing this is to do the scenario description of the road.e.g. There are 3 cars on the road, one is stationary and 2 are in motion.

Comment: Hi @Akash, Have you made any headway since you asked this question?

I am not sure if Optical Flow information is right for your problem. Because if the vehicle is stationary, there will be no change in the flow to identify that stationary vehicle. Optical Flow looks useful in conjunction with the detection system as it provides motion data of the detected object.

However, I did some research and this LearnOpenCV material may be helpful to you: https://www.learnopencv.com/object-tracking-using-opencv-cpp-python/.

Best regards!

Comment: @ThiagoRTK Not much progress.. I have seen this blog, problem with this is it detects object only at the first frame and tracks it. If new object comes in between, it will not be able to track..

Comment: Only optical flow will not help as we also want to find the object i.e. whether it is car or human. That is why we want to do object detection and optical flow.

Comment: Hi @Akash, I understand the idea to use Yolo and Optical Flow (OF) together, but, with Yolo doing the detection and OF extracting motion features from the detected object. So, let me see if I understand your problem right, ok? You want to use the OF to detect and put a bounding box in an object when the Yolo fails, is this, right? If I understand right, even if OF works to build a bounding box in moving objects, the OF also will fail if the object is stationary... I'm just trying to clarify to see if I can help you, ok?

Comment: About that LearnOpenCV material (with tracking approach). I did not look in detail. But wouldn't it be possible to adapt the material so that each Yolo detection is the starting point for tracking? That way, it would be an extra layer to not to lose the object if Yolo fails ...

Comment: Basically I want to detect object and then track it to find whether the object is in motion or not. Now I am thinking to use Yolo for object detection and Kalman Filter for tracking using SORT model. End of the day my requirement is to show as output "There are 2 cars in motion and 1 car stationary". something like that..

Comment: Hi @Akash, I hope you already got it. Kalman filter looks a great idea.

Anyway, from what you said in the last message and also from what you presented in your question. You already have this result... Just calculate the OF values average within each bounding box created by YOLO. Then set some movement threshold from the OF values. Not?